# Code file templates in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, ide

Xcode has a feature where each type of file has a template that is filled out when that type of file is created. By default, those files are located at `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates`.

These files are used to give whatever default code you want, such as a common file header, even including things like the copyright year. I've gotten quite used to the functionality in Xcode, but I find myself missing it in Visual Studio. With VS I have to manually copy-paste the header and modify it myself for each file. Is there a way to get Visual Studio to automatically populate files (such as cpp's or .h's) with code?

EDIT: I'm trying to do this with C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use templates with macros etc in Visual Studio as well. MSDN has an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) on it, and there are various blog posts on the topic too. I know they work for C# and VB - I *expect* C++ works in the same sort of way, but you'll need to check of course. (Apologies if this isn't the case.)

Unfortunately last time I looked it required expanding and then compressing zip files in a way that seemed a little unnecessary, but it should be doable.

Comment: Great link, but it looks like I can't make C++ file templates using that method. I edited my question to specify that I'm using C++.

Comment: @Kyle: Rats - apologies for that. I'm afraid I don't have any more answers then :(

Comment: At least now I know it doesn't look like it's possible. :-)